# How Can I Get an Email Notification When Someone Answers My Questiion?

Tags: discussion

In WordReference Forum,for instance,  where you can post your questions on language, you get an email notification whenever someone answers your question

Does StackExchange offer that facility? If yes, how do I activate it?

If not, would the people behind StackExchange consider introducing it?

Thank you?

Comment: This question really belongs in the meta stackexchange area.

Comment: Really the Meta for all of SE, not the bicycles.se meta.

Answer (score 5):

When you ask a question, theres a checkbox which says "Send me new responses to my posts via email (settings)" below the box where the body of the question is asked.

The settings allow you to get new responses every 3 hours, daily or weekly and it allows you to specify what email address to send the responses to.

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't find the checkbox.

Comment: Updated with a screenshot.

Comment: I suspect that only appears if you've previously updated your profile with your email address.

Comment: SE has my email address (I get the newsletter) but this tick box does not appear for me.   I have adblock disabled on stackexchange, and I do receive emails about bounty reminders, so SE knows how to email me.

Comment: @Criggie no idea, it appears for me. Unverified email, maybe? I'm just guessing, you might have to ask the general meta.SE forum. Multiple posts there already... [generic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122320/does-stack-exchange-have-email-notification-option) and definitively [email notifications blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/10/improved-global-email-notifications/) and [more help](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171051/how-does-one-get-email-notifications-from-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 1):

Strangely, I can't see the checkbox despite setting up settings for email notifications every 3 hours.

On the desktop computer, I use Chrome browser.

Nor does it appear when I use SE's mobile app.

Comment: @Criggie, In preferences, I have now saved the email settings by clicking on the "save email settings" button and a popup window appeared saying that from now I will get the unread messages every 3 hours. Maybe, I had not pressed this button earlier. You may please try doing this.